# SAS ODBC Connection Error

Tags: mysql, odbc, sas

I am trying to use SAS v9.0 to connect to a MySQL database on a Windows 7 machine. Below is the code I am using.

```
proc sql;
connect to odbc(datasrc=localhost user= root password=password);
create table tmp as 
select * 
from connection to odbc 
(  
select * from mysql.time_zone 
)  
;
quit;
```

This is giving me following error.

```
ERROR: CLI error trying to establish connection: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

I am using the MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver.

Comment: You'll increase your chances of getting a good answer if you go back and "accept" answers to some of your prior questions.

Comment: I am a newbie here and didn't know how to accept. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Go back to some of your prior questions, pick the best answer, hover over the outline of a check-mark (under the vote score) and click to accept.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a piece missing from the start of your question?

Comment: Oh sorry..just noticed !I was just mentioning the SAS version . its SAS 9.0 and i am not able to connect it to local mysql server using ODBC.

Comment: I recommend you add `disconnect from odbc;` prior to quitting the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't set your ODBC data source in windows. Go to start->control panel->system and security->administration->ODBC data sources. Select "add", provide all information asked. Then you should provided ODBC data source name when you submit your proc sql datasrc option.

Comment: datasrc options requies not the server name, but the odbc data source name.

Comment: Thanks Boris. I had installed ODBC Driver. The issue was that I had installed a 32 Bit Driver on a 64 Bit mysql server. I have fixed it now.

Comment: @SumitGupta: If you've figured out the answer to your question, please post an answer and accept it.